# Can $k\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$ ever be isomorphic as rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integers

Can  $k\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$ , $k, m \in\mathbb{Z}$,ever be isomorphic as rings ?

This question came upon me when I'm doing/proving that

$2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic as rings, but the proof is rather ad-hoc. Hence this leads me to wonder does there exist a $m, k,m\neq k$ such that $k\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic rings?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: let me edit my post, sorry about that.

Comment: $k\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic as rings if $k \neq m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that an isomorphism of rings must be an isomorphism of the underlying additive group. For any $k,m\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, $k\Bbb Z\cong m\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z$ as abelian groups, and an isomorphism of these groups must send a generator to a generator. There are two generators of each ($\pm k$, $\pm m$, and $\pm 1$, respectively), and a morphism $(k\Bbb Z,+)\to (m\Bbb Z,+)$ is uniquely determined by the image of $k$. Thus, the only isomorphisms of groups between $k\Bbb Z$ and $m\Bbb Z$ are induced by the maps $\phi : k\mapsto m$ and $\psi : k\mapsto -m$. Now, you need to check when these are/are not isomorphisms of rings.

Consider $\phi(k^2)$. This is equal to $\phi(k\cdot k) = k\phi(k) = km$, because an abelian group is a $\Bbb Z$-module and $\phi$ is a morphism of abelian groups. But, for $\phi$ to be a ring homomorphism, you must also have $\phi(k^2) = \phi(k)^2 = m^2$. (Don't forget that we haven't thought about when $k$ or $m$ is $0$, and remember to also consider $\psi$!)

Comment: Ahhh nice, now we have a contradiction. Case 1: m = 0, this will contradict injectivity, case 2 m not zero, then we can cancel, and this will contradict k not equal m

Comment: @some1fromhell Again, I'll remind you to consider $\psi$ as well. Just because $\phi$ isn't an isomorphism doesn't mean there is *no* isomorphism.

Comment: I see, thank you so much